# Concat html tag within a strings in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, string, string-interpolation

I basically to concat html tag  within a string like that `"Click this  link <Link to = "/home">go to home</Link> for going to home page"`
How can i do that in react js.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: You only have one string, what do you mean by `concat`?

Answer (score 1):

I would put the text in a `p element` - and the text fragments within `spans` and assuming you are importing your Link component and router - it should be as simple as

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

import Link from "../../compoments/Link/Link";


<p>
  <span>Click this  link</span>
  <Link to = "/home">go to home</Link>
  <span> for going to home page</span>
</p>
```

Comment: i also know this way but i basically want to cancat string and html tag is that possible in some way

Comment: The question you should be asking yourself is - why would I try to a) re-invent the router wheel , b) not use the eestablished methods and c) circument good logical code structure to tryo to get some intpolation between a string and a JSX component. The established pathway is simple, logical and re-useable. IMO